# How to implement Linq Where In query with an array

Tags: sql, linq

Can we build a Linq where clause really like SQL In? Like:

```
int[] ids = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};    
var query = from item in db.myTable
            where item.ID In ids
            select item;
```

I know we can use a Contains keyword like below but I want to split the where clause without that local array ids so that I can save the where clause in a table to reuse it. I will save the real data { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5} in DB but not a local variable.

```
int[] ids = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};    
var query = from item in db.myTable
            where ids.Contains(item.ID)
            select item;
```

Comment: So the question is not about how to do WHERE IN with an array, but rather how to do it based on values in another table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query should follow a similar pattern, you'll just pull the values from the other table instead of having them in an array.

```
var ids = db.someTable.Where(...).Select(e => e.ID);
var query = from item in db.myTable
        where ids.Contains(item.ID)
        select item;
```

Comment: I want to save the where clause in a table as the search result from users so it can be re-executed when the user log in again. Problem here is I can't save the ids.Contains(some array) because it is depending on a local variable. I want to save the real data value { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}. Can I save a one-line where clause for above example?

Comment: @YePeng: Right. Create a table, e.g., with UserId and ItemId in it. Save entries for the user and the items the user has selected. Then, where I say `someTable` in my code above, query the table that you've saved these values in. Filter by the current user ID, then select the ItemId values. That gives you an `IQueryable<int>` that you can use in the `Contains()` portion of the `query` you create afterward.

Comment: I really wanted to have a inline clause with all data included but it seems like impossible. I think your solution it is the right direction. I have to build another table to store the Contains data and the put them together to reuse. thank you.

Comment: @YePeng: I'm not sure what you mean by an inline clause with all data included. You could just inline the `ids` variable in the code above, and it would have the same effect. But why do you want to do that?

Comment: actually this is an old design from existing code that there is a field called WhereClause in my table which stores the where clause from last user query. The purpose is to restore last select query from any user. I can use field name (like UserID) or real value (like ( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)) but I can't use a local variable name (like ids).